# Typographic text for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, typography

How they do this typographic text. do they create UIView for each style?

Does any one know how ?

[image: Typographic text]

Answer (score 2):

Try an `NSAttributedString`. Attributed strings allow you to change the font and look of each section of a string per your desires.

Documentation: `https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html`

Comment: is this image , is there only one UILabel or 4 label. or even not a label ? also how to put that typography style?

Comment: All of the text could be done with a single label. The line around it, and the background is an image for sure. It is possible that the text is actually hard coded on the image, but it could also be an attributed string

Comment: i have tried and got text working. but could not get the idea of adding different style . should i create UIView for each different style.

Comment: I'm looking for the same feature, is there any documentation?